# How can I display a J2ME Ticker in top of the screen?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I'm trying to display a `Ticker` in the top of the screen but by default it's always in the bottom and I couldn't find anything that changes its position, I found an answer suggesting **LWUIT** but I don't understand what it is or how to use it, any solution for this code?

```
Ticker tk = new Ticker("ASPHALT-CAR RACE");
this.setTicker(tk);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Ticker.html):

> The direction and speed of scrolling are determined by the
>   implementation.

If you are using LCDUI Forms there is not much you can do, but if you are using Canvas you can implement your custom ticker using Graphics.

Comment: and how can I do that?

Comment: LCDUI is the high level GUI / "Form API" that MIDP was born with, so it's quite old and limited. LWUIT is a kind of modern replacement for LCDUI, so that's what you want to be using if you're annoyed by the limitations of LCDUI.